# Effective difference between short- and longhanded form of array initialization

Tags: arrays, swift

The final experiment within the [Swift Guided Tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html) asks the reader to:

> Modify the anyCommonElements(_:_:) function to make a function that
>   returns an array of the elements that any two sequences have in
>   common.

My first quick pass at modification:

```
func anyCommonElements <T: SequenceType, U: SequenceType where T.Generator.Element: Equatable, T.Generator.Element == U.Generator.Element> (lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> [T.Generator.Element] {
    var commonElements = [T.Generator.Element]()
    for lhsItem in lhs {
        for rhsItem in rhs {
            if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                commonElements.append(lhsItem)
            }
        }
    }
    return commonElements
}
```

I receive an error related to my initialization of the array `commonElements` on line 2 in Xcode 7.1.1:

> Invalid use of '[]' to call a value of non-function type
>   '[T.Generator.Element.Type]'

However, if I simply change the initialization to use the longhand form of creating an empty array on line 2 everything works perfectly and without error:

```
func anyCommonElements <T: SequenceType, U: SequenceType where T.Generator.Element: Equatable, T.Generator.Element == U.Generator.Element> (lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> [T.Generator.Element] {
    var commonElements = Array<T.Generator.Element>() // Longhanded empty array
    for lhsItem in lhs {
        for rhsItem in rhs {
            if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                commonElements.append(lhsItem)
            }
        }
    }
    return commonElements
}
```

In [the Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105) it states:

> The type of a Swift array is written in full as `Array<Element>`, where
>   Element is the type of values the array is allowed to store. You can
>   also write the type of an array in shorthand form as `[Element]`.
>   **Although the two forms are functionally identical, the shorthand form
>   is preferred** and is used throughout this guide when referring to the
>   type of an array.

*(Emphasis added.)*

If they "are functionally identical", why am I receiving an error in my first example above apparently just because I used the shorthand form to create an empty array? Or—perhaps more likely—am I lacking a fundamental understanding of the problem at hand?

Comment: `var commonElements : [T.Generator.Element] = []` this also works.

Comment: Might be a bug. [Have you filed one?](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: Was expecting more ppl with this issue here. No one does homework from the Swift book :)